# Perforce : is there any better way to comment one line in client spec?

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

i used to -//depot/xxx.. but its not good because i need to write the correct depot path after -//.... is there any better way to comment this ?
such as :#//depot/xxx..

Comment: Specifically, you use `-//depot/xxx__Compiled_Object_files //idbrii/NUL` format to create comments.

Answer (score 6):

[You can't.](http://osdir.com/ml/version-control.perforce/2005-06/msg00051.html)

The clientspec you see is just the output from the perforce database. It gets parsed when saved, so any comments would disappear the next time you load the clientspec.

Answer (score 6):

The best I can think of is if you add something in the **Description:** field and copy the text into the **View:** field when needed.